# edges of transparent video visible in images as planes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I have imported a video (PNG Sequence with Alpha) using Images as Planes. When rendering in Cycles you can see the edges of the video and I can't get rid of them. It's very subtle but it's still there. Thanks for your help!

[image: Edges / Images as Planes]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like very faint "smoke" at the edge of the original clip, its not truly transparent at the edges (cause of the smoke). Open the image sequence and place a solid background behind it and then zoom in and see if you can see tiny smoke particles at the edges, check the first frame and progress to the last.

Answer (score 0):

I rendered in "fast mode" with e-cycles which caused the edges to appear!